# Rails 3 Compatibility Issue (Mac Snow Leopard 32 Bit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 on older iMac that is Core Duo, so it's 32-bit only. When I went to the terminal, I saw that I have Ruby 1.8.7, RubyGems 1.3.5, and Rails 2.3.5. I want to upgrade my Rails to 3 - which IS supported with Ruby 1.8.7 - and tried to do with RVM and all, but could not do so. I now almost suspect if it's the compatibility issue between Rails and RubyGems, but I'm not sure. I also do not seem to be able to upgrade RubyGems either.

If anyone can help, that would be great...I am not even sure if it's possible in the system since two resources on this issue - one by Hive Logic and another from Rails Installer - both spoke only of 64-bit systems. Is Rails 3 not possible in 32-bit only systems? Or is there any other issue that I'm not aware of?

UPDATE: I'm putting updates from my terminal. Thanks to everyone taking a look!

```
gem install rails
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
  /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/labuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
  gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
```

UPDATE 2: Okay, so I tried again after installing RVM. I did it yesterday but deleted RVM after it wasn't working...but maybe someone can see what this means!

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Can not find compiler and 'make' tool - make sure Xcode and/or Command Line Tools are installed.
```

UPDATE 3 (Resolved): Figured I would update it in case anyone has a similar problem in the future. I had to use sudo command to get things going... I wasn't able to upgrade my Ruby version (stuck at 1.8.7) but RubyGems and Rails both got updated, so things were able to move...It's not really smooth though, and I'm encountering additional problems that I didn't see before (just FYI).

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: It gave me errors. As in, when I tried to upgrade any of three - Ruby, RubyGems, or Rails - I got errors in red saying that it is not possible. And when I checked the version, nothing changed.

Comment: Oh, errors. Maybe it'd be useful to know something about those errors. *Edit* I'd really recommend using rvmrbenv/etc instead of replacing your system Ruby's gems.

Comment: @user2373356: What errors?

Comment: Based on the error saying you don't have make, i would guess you don't have xcode or command line tools installed.  You will need them or another package that gives you gcc.  If you are goign down th xcode path, be aware you will need to upgrade OSX to get the version from the app store to run.

Comment: That error didn't come first so I don't know why it did... I did install XCode afterwards through Snow Leopard DVD that I have. Will this not be enough? I'm not sure if my system supports higher XCode since I presume those will be geared for 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

To install rails/ruby on mac, here is what is needed.

1. Get the development tools: Install compatible version of Xcode & the needed tools to compile ruby will get bundled. or get the CLI Tools download.
2. Use rvm to install latest ruby. Don't use ruby `1.8.7`, always `1.9.3` or newer.

The CLI Tools download is not supported for Snow leopard, I think. so your only option now is to find a version of xcode that's compatible with `Mac OS X SL` & then use rvm.

Here is a direct link to [XCode 3.2.6 for Snow Leopard directly from Apple](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg) which I found after running a google search.

Lastly, as you may have noticed being on SL puts you on disadvantage & makes development hard. so I would advice you to upgrade to latest supported release.